# Symfony2 Assetic Custom File Combiner

Tags: javascript, symfony, assetic

I'm working on a system which needs to have a number of files combined together with a custom combiner (i.e., not just glued together with Assetic).

The combiner is primarily to handle ordering them (JavaScript "classes") in an order that handles dependencies.

My current plan is to have a filter which processes something like .x.js files, which will essentially contain the instructions my custom combiner needs to put things together properly. Then I'll create some other bit of something which would make the uncombined files available in the dev environment (like Assetic would if I just let it combine files).

The uncombined files wouldn't be presented to Assetic at all (which means I can't use any other filters, etc.)

My question is: does Assetic have a better way for me to implement a customer combiner that would let me use more of its innate functionality while still being able to control the file order (without having to hard-code it in the Twig files).

Thanks.

Comment: I just combine them with assetic and control file order by manipulating file names. Quick and easy.

Comment: That's not really feasible for a project as large as the one this is for. We have things akin to "include" commands in our JavaScript to let our custom builder/combiner make sure things get loaded in an order that ensures everything is in an acceptable order.